# kotlin : what is difference between isNullOrEmpty and isNullOrBlank?

Tags: kotlin

I want check value of my EditText in android so I saw two function for my String value :

> user.isNullOrBlank()

and

> user.isNullOrEmpty()

**what is difference between them?**

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`isNullOrBlank()` takes whitespace into account:

```
fun main() {
  val thisIsBlank = "   "

  println(thisIsBlank.isNullOrEmpty())
  println(thisIsBlank.isNullOrBlank())
}
```

This prints:

```
false
true
```

because `thisIsBlank` is not empty, but it is blank.

Comment: _empty_ refers to an empty string (a string with no characters, whose length is zero), whereas _blank_ refers to a string that is either empty or consists entirely of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 15):

`isNullOrEmpty()`

- returns **true** for a string with no characters and/or zero length as @Wyck commented.
- returns **false** for whitespace.

`isNullOrBlank()`

- returns **true** for a string with no characters and/or zero length. Same as isNullOrEmpty()
- and will ALSO return **true** for whitespace. Different than isNullOrEmpty().